# JSFiddle code not working when implemented into website, Coding in Dreamweaver. JS

Tags: javascript, loading, dreamweaver, jsfiddle

I am new to jQuery but I have spent the week trying to get this working outside of JSFiddle. I started using JSFiddle as it seemed like a good platform to learn in but composing the code outside of JSFiddle is turning out to be a daunting task. I might be missing something quite simple or perhaps JSFiddle just taught me enough to be dangerous. I wouldn't have asked on here if I hadn't searched for solutions on here and through google so any help would be much appreciated. I am trying implement this code into my website that I am coding in dreamweaver CS5.

Here is the link to the JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/OFJavascript/9QtVw/

I am linking the CSS like this within the "head" tags

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="JavaScript/GraphicNav.css" />
```

I am linking the JavaScript like this within the "head" tags

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="JavaScript/GraphicNav.js"></script>
```

I am dropping the HTML in the "body" tags

Here is the first part of my html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript/GraphicNav.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="JavaScript/GraphicNav.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
<body>
<div id='wrap'>
   <div class='pathnavbg1'></div>
   <div class='pathnavbg2'></div>
   <div class='pathnavbg3'></div>
   <div class='pathnavbg4'></div>
    <div id='action1'><span><div id='link1'><H1 class='pathnavtext'>LINKLINK01</H1></div></span></div>
   <div id='action2'><span><div id='link2'><H1 class='pathnavtext'>LINKLINK02</H1></div></span></div>
   <div id='action3'><span><div id='link3'><H1 class='pathnavtext'>LINKLINK03</H1></div></span></div>
   <div id='inner1'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec nisl ut nibh suscipit molestie. Phasellus bibendum nulla tincidunt mi sagittis vel fermentum elit aliquam. Quisque sit amet odio est. Duis condimentum mattis dolor vitae consectetur. Mauris adipiscing laoreet auctor. Sed vel sapien metus.</div>
   <div id='inner2'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec nisl ut nibh suscipit molestie. Phasellus bibendum nulla tincidunt mi sagittis vel fermentum elit aliquam. Quisque sit amet odio est. Duis condimentum mattis dolor vitae consectetur. Mauris adipiscing laoreet auctor. Sed vel sapien metus.</div>
   <div id='inner3'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec nisl ut nibh suscipit molestie. Phasellus bibendum nulla tincidunt mi sagittis vel fermentum elit aliquam. Quisque sit amet odio est. Duis condimentum mattis dolor vitae consectetur. Mauris adipiscing laoreet auctor. Sed vel sapien metus.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Again hopefully it is something simple I'm missing. Any help is much appreciated as I have exhausted all methods of making this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle put your code in the ready to function, and the function is simple.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(function () {
    $("document").ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#action1").trigger('click');
        }, 10);
    });


    $('#action1').click(

    );
    $("#action1").click(

    );


    $('#action2').click(

    );
    $("#action2").click(

    );
    // code here
});//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: So if I added everything within the document ready, moving the }); to the bottom, it should work? I'm assuming I don't need to wrap it in script tags if I am attaching it as a seperate .js?

Comment: Put your code ready to function, then you can go out alone. `$(function(){  // you code });` and `$(document).read(function(){  // you code });`.

Comment: wow super simple fix thanks! everything is looking good and working now

Answer (score 0):

Put all your .click() calls inside your ready function. Probably the time it's called, the element is not yet ready.

Comment: Thanks I am attempting to fix it now, did I link my external JavaScript and CSS properly?

Answer (score 0):

you can always view source code for the iframe of that page and than copy and paste it to whatever program you are using and than upload it to your website.